# Tensorial direct product

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, linear-algebra

The direct product of two tensors is also a tensor. I would like to know if we can write a tensor as a product of only two other tensors. For example, how to find $A^{\mu}$ and $ B^{\nu}$ so that $\eta^{\mu\nu}= A^{\mu}B^{\nu}$?

Comment: I'm not sure if that quite works as an actual tensor product, notationally. You might need to use the notation for an outer product. In general, I think you can contract two tensors to produce a third, a process which has a lot in common with matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

This is not always possible. For example, the tensor

$$
\delta^{ij} = \begin{cases}1\quad\text{when}\,i=j\\0\quad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

cannot be written as $A^iB^j$ which we can see from the fact that the matrix of $\delta^{ij}$ is the identity matrix which is full rank while the matrix of $A^iB^j$ is rank one.

Minkowski metric $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ is also full rank and hence there do not exist $A^\mu$ and $B^\nu$ such that $\eta^{\mu\nu} = A^\mu B^\nu$.

In general, you need more than one term of the form $A^iB^j$ to represent a given tensor $C^{ij}$

$$
C^{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^r A_k^iB_k^j
$$

where $r$ is the rank of $C^{ij}$ and $A_k$ and $B_k$ are tensors. This is a restatement of the singular value decomposition for matrices and has a generalization, called [tensor rank decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_rank_decomposition), to tensors with arbitrary number of indices.

Answer (score 1):

The product $A^\mu B^\nu$ is a tensor (assuming  $A^\mu$ and $B^\nu$ are tensors).

However, for a general tensor like $Q^{\mu\nu}$,

no, $Q^{\mu\nu}$ cannot be generally written as product like $A^\mu B^\nu$.

However, it may written as a sum of such products
$Q^{\mu\nu}=\sum_i A_i^\mu\ B_i^\nu$.

For example, if $Q^{\mu\nu}$ is anti-symmetric, then it cannot be written as $A^\mu B^\nu$... but would require something like
$A^\mu B^\nu - B^\mu A^\nu$.